# CSS footer from cssstickyfooter.com not working correctly

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I got some simple CSS from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ to get a footer that always sticks no matter how long the content is. Now, this isn't actually working. I'm having two different problems with this footer, but I'm going to ask them both here because I suspect they're related.

First here's the css from the site:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;}
```

And here's the HTML I'm using for the whole page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title_text}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/global/global.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            {$navbar}<hr><div id="content">{$body}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {$footer}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are some variables formatted as `{$variable}`. These are pulled from another file/string.

#### Problem 1:

The footer is too high and overlaps with the other content on the page. Here's what that looks like:

[image: this footer is overlapping!]

To try to solve this problem, what I did was I added 200px of padding to the div of ID `wrap`, which is right before the footer (see HTML above). This will fix the problem you see in the picture there. But it causes another issue: now on pages with very little content, the footer is still moved down 200px, and you have to scroll down to see it. The site I got this CSS code from said this shouldn't happen.

#### Problem 2:

The footer doesn't reach the edges of the browser's window. Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]

The footer should be "touching" the right and left sides of the window, but as you can see, there seems to be a small margin. Honestly, I'm not sure how to start fixing this. But I don't think it's a bug because it renders the same way in Chrome, Firefox, and I think even in Internet Explorer.

Any input is welcome. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html doesn't appear to match your css.  Your css contains a '#main' but your main content appears in

```
<div id="content">...</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. But that's actually not it, I changed everything from main to content, including the CSS. The CSS I pasted into the question came directly from that site I linked to, without the changes. I can post the changes if you'd like.

Comment: ya..should probably post or update w/ the code that's breaking.

Comment: Wow, you were right. I stand corrected! I went to get the CSS like you said, and found that I had not, in fact, changed it to "content". Oops!

Comment: And that fixed Problem 1. I guess it wasn't related to problem 2 after all.

Comment: may want to spin off question2 into new question..else this may get long.  Have anything in your that controls width of #footer?

Comment: Well, @DaneSoul's suggestion of adding a padding and margin of 0 seemed to work, so yeah I'm going to write a new question so he can get credit for that. Thanks for the quick response, it *really* helped!

Answer (score 1):

1)  Try change

```
#footer { position: relative; }
```

to `#footer {position: absolute; }`

2) Add to your code

`html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` to prevent spaces around your footer

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Since @ltiong_sh already solved Problem 1 and I accepted his answer, I feel like it would only be right to ask about Problem 2 in another question. I'm going to link to that question when I write it so that you can answer it.

Comment: Can you answer it again here so you can get credit for it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843657/sticky-footer-doesnt-reach-the-right-and-left-sides-of-browser-window