# Sticky footer doesn't reach the right and left sides of browser window

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

Continuation from [CSS footer from cssstickyfooter.com not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843522/css-footer-from-cssstickyfooter-com-not-working-correctly#10843570)

This footer from http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ isn't reaching the edges of the Browser's window:

[image: bad footer]

The footer should be "touching" the right and left sides of the window, but as you can see, there seems to be a small margin. Honestly, I'm not sure how to start fixing this. But I don't think it's a bug because it renders the same way in Chrome, Firefox, and I think even in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your code

```
html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

to prevent spaces around your footer